# Program to reverse a number without using an array

Tags: c, logic

This is the code that I used. It works perfectly, but I don't understand why it works. I just kept changing my original logic until I started using -1 in the counter loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int number, reverse, sum =0;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    int temp = number;
    int ctr;

    for(ctr = -1; temp!=0; ctr++)
        temp = temp/10;

    while(number)
    {
        sum = sum + (number%10 * (pow(10, ctr--)));
        number = number/10; 
    }
    printf("%d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and step though the code line by line, while checking the values of all variables.

Comment: Means you are asking us the logic of your own code?

Comment: A debugger might help, but it's probably better to walk through the code, and just keep track of variable values and what they'll do.  A debugger might be overkill.

Comment: `printf` is also good for this. I would print `sum`, `number`, `ctr`, and `pow(10, ctr)` in the loop. That should make it obvious why the code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same basic math but so much easier to understand:

```
unsigned int number = 123456789;
unsigned int reversed = 0;
do {
    reversed *= 10;
    reversed += number % 10;
    number /= 10; 
} while (number > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is kind of awkward to explain the logic of the code that you wrote it yourself, I understood the logic behind it.

Indeed, I was looking for a solution to solve this problem: ***How to reverse any positive integer without using arrays or indexed variables*** to which your code was the solution I was looking for.

The logic of your programme is like this:

you first count the digits of the given number in the ***FOR-loop*** in the shortest possible way. you need this because you have to 10-power each remainder up to digits of the given number in the next ***WHILE-loop*** and you store/add the result of this each time in the variable named ***SUM***. The final result of this would be the whole integer to be reversed.

PS1:

You do not need the variable named ***REVERSE***. Just drop it or replace ***SUM*** with it.

PS2:
You really do not need to go that long way to do this. Here's another shorter version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (void){
    unsigned short int uNum, nReversed;

    puts ("Enter a positive integer number: ");
    scanf ("%hu", &uNum);

    while (uNum != 0){
        nReversed = uNum%10 + nReversed*10 ;
        uNum /= 10;
    }
    printf ("\n\n\nThat is %d", nReversed);
}
```